# How to run single test in grails-core project using Gradle?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, gradle

I'm trying to add a new test case to existing test `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.ReverseUrlMappingTests` in `grails-test-suite-web` submodule of `grails-core` project.

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-test-suite-web/src/test/groovy/org/grails/web/mapping/ReverseUrlMappingTests.groovy

I have a problem with running single test case using Gradle. When I do:

```
./gradlew -Dtest.single=ReverseUrlMappingTests :grails-test-suite-web:test
```

It ends with:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> Could not find matching test for pattern: ReverseUrlMappingTests

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

This test can be run in full test cycle `./gradlew test` but it's waste of the time when we wanna red-green-refactor only one simple test case. I also noticed that the same problem occurs when I try to run in the same manner spock.lang.Specification subclass test.

**Here's my question:** is it possible to run single grails-core test with Gradle?

It's grails-core `2.4.x` branch clone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has been edited to indicate that the test is on the 2.4.x branch, which affects the answer.  I have made relevant changes below.

Something like this will work...

```
 ./gradlew :g-t-s-w:test --tests *ReverseUrlMappingTests*
```

When you do that, you are still going to be running some other tests because of the way our build is written.  If you want to get rid of them you can comment out the following:

```
test.dependsOn execIsolatedTests
```

That is in `grails-test-suite-web/build.gradle` at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/644233cfff266f391c44ef3ec56036a3b1c9bb19/grails-test-suite-web/build.gradle#L98

You could also do something like this...

```
./gradlew -DsingleTest.single=ReverseUrlMappingTests grails-test-suite-web:singleTest
```

Comment: Hey Jeff, thanks for your support! I did check your suggestion, it didnt work - https://gist.github.com/wololock/23bf63e1c855b1df8fbb. I have found `singleTest` task in `build.gradle` - running test using this task did the trick. Should we update wiki page https://grails.org/GrailsDevEnvironment ? Or is this some kind of anomaly?

Comment: Why do you have quotes around the test pattern?

Comment: `zsh: no matches found: -Dtest.single=**/*ReverseUrlMappingTests*` if I run without quotes

Comment: It's a clone of `2.4.x`

Comment: If you are using 2.4.x you probably want the `--tests` approach.

Comment: The following command works on the 2.4.x branch... `./gradlew :g-t-s-w:test --tests *ReverseUrlMappingTests*`.

Comment: Yes, it run, but the bunch of other tests run as well. It took `Total time: 1 mins 16.061 secs` :( while `singleTest` task took "only" `Total time: 21.273 secs`

Comment: Did you see my comment in the answer about the other tests?  You can comment out the depends if you don't want them to run.  I also think the singleTest task can be used if you don't want the other tests.  I don't think we added that until 2.4.x though.

Comment: Yes, I saw your comment - in fact it works after commenting out that line. `singleTest` was added in May 2014, so it's quite fresh approach to run single test.